# Analyses Services Cube: Change a View in a Db and seeing the results in Excel

Tags: ssas, olap, cube, bids

I have a Cube already made with BIDS. But now i must modify one thing. The cube takes some views made in sql server db, so not the tables. I made some changes directly in the view but the columns and names remained the same. But when I click on update in excel I don't see this changes. Is there something I need to do like deploying the cube again or the changes made in db views are enough?

Thank you.

Comment: Unless you deploy the cube, the changes won't reflect.

Comment: But shouldn't the changes be visible without deploying? Because the tables used for the cube are the same as before. Only thing i did was one change in the view used so instead of having select column1 as Abc i have select case when a then a else b end as Abc.

Comment: Cube pre-aggregates and stores data. That's how it works(unless it ROLAP). So, if the output of a view changes, then cube has to be re-processed.

Comment: Thanks, indeed I just had to login to analysis services and reprocess the cube in order to see the changes.